# Android - Layout is Useless warning

Tags: android, android-layout

I was making a settings page and I get this warning: `This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to 
 the other view`

Here's the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/settings_sound_toggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textOn="Sound On"
            android:textOff="Sound Off"
            android:onClick="soundToggleClick"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/settings_highscore_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/clear_highscore"
            android:onClick="highscoreResetClick" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the `ToggleButton` and `Button` views to be vertically centered. Is there a simpler & better way to do this that removes the warning?

Comment: use `gravity` and remove the relative layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can center all views in your LinerarLayout

notice the difference between:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

and

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

- "gravity" tells the container to center all the child-views inside the container
- "layout_gravity" tells the view how it should be aligned in the parent container

your layout should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/settings_sound_toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textOn="Sound On"
        android:textOff="Sound Off"
        android:onClick="soundToggleClick"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/settings_highscore_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/clear_highscore"
        android:onClick="highscoreResetClick" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to  the other view.
 This is just a warning because You using RelativeLayout as your parent and then defining only one linear layout inside that.So it would be better for you to just use either LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

The `RelativeLayout` has just one child and is therefore useless. You can remove it and make the `LinearLayout` the top element.

Only the background needs to be specified at the `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting rid of the linear Layout all together and use this in relative layout?

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/settings_sound_toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:onClick="soundToggleClick"
        android:textOff="Sound Off"
        android:textOn="Sound On" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_highscore_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="highscoreResetClick"
        android:text="@string/clear_highscore" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_highscore_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="highscoreResetClick"
        android:text="@string/clear_highscore" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/settings_sound_toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_highscore_reset"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="soundToggleClick"
        android:textOff="Sound Off"
        android:textOn="Sound On" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or you can use `GridLayout` to center it properly.

Or you can use something like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_highscore_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="highscoreResetClick"
        android:text="@string/clear_highscore" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/settings_sound_toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="soundToggleClick"
        android:textOff="Sound Off"
        android:textOn="Sound On" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know this is not good way to approch the problem. It's just an opinion if its fine with you. I personaly wont use such code in projects. I Hope it helps :D

Also Sandro Machado got the best answer if you fine with using only LinearLayout as parent. because you anyways are not using the relativelayout atributes.